# How to change tmp repertory for firefox downloads

Tags: linux, firefox, download

I just made a clean install of my Debian system and when it comes to partitionning the hard drive i choose the option with /, /home, /var /usr and /tmp are on seperate partition this time. Then i let the default config for the partition table.

Now i have a problem whatever is firefox (iceweasel in fact) downloads directory, it in fact download to /tmp and then copy the entire file to that location when the download is finished.

My problem is that my /tmp partition is to small for some of my downloads, so for now i have to use `wget` instead but that's not very convenient. I know that some firefox add-ons could make firefox use `wget` for each downloads but i don't want that.

So my question is, how to tell firefox to downloads in a specific directory *during the downloading process*? (Is that even possible?)

I took a look at about:config but i didn't saw anything that seems related to what i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the source code ([`xpcom/io/SpecialSystemDirectory.cpp`: lines 419-433](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/615528/xpcom/io/SpecialSystemDirectory.cpp#l450)) you can set any of the environment variables TMPDIR, TMP, or TEMP to the path of the directory where you want your temporary files to be stored.

Comment: I didn't even thought of taking a look at the source code... Thank you, i'll use TEMP since i feel this is the one of the three which will affect the less program (TMP and TMPDIR sound more unix/linux-y than TEMP).

Comment: @p4bl0 No need to set the environment variable globally for everything. You can say `TEMP=~/mytempdirfortoday iceweasel` whenever you need it or put your own script into a path with higher precedence. Assuming you have `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` set in your `.profile` an executable file named `iceweasel` there with `#!/bin/sh
TEMP=~/mytempdir exec /usr/bin/iceweasel` will override.